# Why won't Chrome detect my audio ended?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, addeventlistener

I've tried several solutions. Both work in Safari, but Chrome stops the audio after playing the file through. Before this there is the getNewAudioFileFunction - which fetches a file from an API, and plays it.
So I want to detect when the audio file is finished, and upon the audio.ended I want to retriever the getNewAudioFileFunction. What is it that I don't get here?

```
audio.onended = function() {
          console.log('Audio Ended');
          getNewAudioFileFunction();
        }
```

and:

```
if  (audio.play(audio)) {
        audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
                console.log(audio.currentTime);
                console.log('audio ended');
                getNewAudioFileFunction();
                });
```